# keycloak-21.0.1 - Issues syncing users with LDAP

Tags: ldap, keycloak, openid-connect

Environment Details: 
keycloak version : 21.0.1 
Free LDAP testing URL: https://www.forumsys.com/2022/05/10/online-ldap-test-server/ 
Based on above URL i have configured but unable to sync. 
[LDAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvZBY.png)
[keycloak_Setting1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pBB6.png)
[keycloak_Setting2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgN0U.png)
[keycloak_Setting3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tp89.png)
[keycloak_Setting4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l45cY.png)
[keycloak_Setting5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXtiW.png)

**Error Message: Sync of users finished successfully.0 users added, 0 users updated, 0 users removed, 20 users failed.**

Log Error:

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (executor-thread-4) Failed during import user from LDAP: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: User returned from LDAP has null username! Check configuration of your LDAP mappings. Mapped username LDAP attribute: uid, user DN: uid=nogroup,dc=example,dc=com, attributes from LDAP: {mail=[nogroup@ldap.forumsys.com], sn=[Group], cn=[No Group]}
```

Please let me know what might be the issue.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: issue resolved after updated below fields.

Username LDAP attribute * = cn
RDN LDAP attribute * =cn

Answer (score 0):

You can add as (uid=*) as "User LDAP filter". I was able to sync users with this. I am using keycloak 21.1.1.
If this doesn't work for you, I can export my realm.